# c++ json read value from [ ]

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

i wanna read Json file with c++, im using dev c++.
Json file:

```
{
"product":{"title":"xxx","rating":4.5,"reviews_total":82,"image":"xxx","asin":"xxx","link":"xxx"},
"offers":[{
"price":{"symbol":"€","currency":"EUR","value":35.78,"raw":"35,78 €"},
"minimum_order_quantity":{"value":1},
"maximum_order_quantity":{"value":30},]
}
```

And i want to read Offers - Price - Value

My code now:

```
#include "json.hpp"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fJson("test.json");
    stringstream buffer;
    buffer << fJson.rdbuf();
    auto json = nlohmann::json::parse(buffer.str());

    cout << "\nPozostalo zapytan: " << json["request_info"]["credits_remaining"] << "\n";
    cout << "Asin: "<< json["request_parameters"]["asin"] <<endl;

    
    cout << "Cena produktu: "<< json["price"]["value"] <<endl;

    return 0;

}
```

showin Asin and credits_remaining works, but i cant get value from offers price, i try to

```
json["offers"]["price"]["value"]
```

i get

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::detail::type_error' what(): [json.exception.type_error.305] cannot use operator[] with a string argument with array

get help or answer :)

Comment: The data for `offers` is a *list* of objects.

Comment: Post/add the error in your question.

Comment: The JSON you have compiled is malformed. There are no offers in the array of objects

Comment: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::detail::type_error'
  what():  [json.exception.type_error.305] cannot use operator[] with a string argument with array

When i try "json["offers"]["price"]["value"]"


when "json["price"]["value"] i get Null

Comment: How about `json["offers"][0]["price"]["value"]` instead?

Comment: json["offers"][0]["price"]["value"]  - works! thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
json["offers"][0]["price"]["value"]
```

Worked for me.